# Versions of jupyter compatible with colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm getting notebooks saved locally in Jupyter notebook miss cells when opened in colab. More than sporadically. Which versions of Jupyter (or Anaconda) are safe to use when doing back and forth between colab and a local setup?

Comment: Also opened https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4307 about this

Comment: Looks like a bug with a response on the GitHub issue.

Comment: I came here after encountering this bug. Looks like it went out of colab teams radar, so I created a bug report in colab issue tracker: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/581